# IF.. post meta show... Conditional Tag Help...?

Tags: query-posts, post-meta, conditional-tags

I have the following conditional tag, which a friend helped me with...

Currently it works doing..

1) If a featured image just show that.

2) If images attached show featured image wrapped in a link  to the images attached..

Can there be a third?

3) If meta data just a text input field rw_post-vimeo just show that, its a Vimeo link..get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rw_post-vimeo',true)

I made an attempt below but it breaks it, is this possible?

```
<ul id="post-list">

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>


<?php
$featured = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_thumbnail_id',true);
$attachments = get_children( 'post_type=attachment&orderby=menu_order&exclude='.$featured.'&post_mime_type=image&post_parent='.$post->ID );
 ?>
 <li class="post">

 <span class="entry-published">
 <time datetime="<?php the_time('Y-m-d')?>"><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></time>
 </span>

 <?php if ( !empty($attachments) ) : ?>
 <div class="entry-specific-content">

<a href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/gallery.php?id='.$post->ID; ?>">

<?php if (has_post_thumbnail()): the_post_thumbnail();else: $first_img = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachments[0]->ID, 'thumbnail-size');  ?>

<img src="<?php echo $first_img[0]; ?>" width="<?php echo $first_img[1]; ?>" height="<?php echo $first_img[2]; ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
</a>
</div>
<div class="yes-gallery">
<a href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/gallery.php?id='.$post->ID; ?>">See Rest Of Images</a>
</div>

<?php else: ?>
<div class="entry-specific-content">
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
</div>
<div class="no-gallery"></div>


<?php else: ?>
<div class="entry-specific-content">
<?php echo do_shortcode('[iframe_loader src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/'. get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rw_post-vimeo',true) .'?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=ffffff&autoplay=1" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0""]');?>

</div>
<div class="no-gallery"></div>

<?php endif; ?>


<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

<div class="entry-content">
<?php the_content(); ?>
</div>


</li>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</ul>
```

Is it possible or no go, another way of doing it?

Thank you for anyones help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I would refactor this a bit:

```
<?php
$featured = ( has_post_thumbnail() ? get_post_thumbnail() : false );
$first_img = false;
$custom = false;

if ( ! $featured ) {
    // No featured image; look for attached images and get the first one
    $attachments = get_children( 'post_type=attachment&orderby=menu_order&post_mime_type=image&post_parent='.$post->ID ); 
    $first_img = ( $attachments ? wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachments[0]->ID, 'thumbnail-size') : false );
    // No attached images; look for custom-field image
    if ( ! $first_img ) {
        $custom_meta = ( get_post_custom($post->ID) ? get_post_custom($post->ID) : false );
        $custom = ( isset( $custom_meta['custom_field_name'][0] ) ? $custom['custom_field_name'][0] : "false" );
    }
}
?>
```

So, now, you can just step through each source; e.g.:

```
<?php
if ( $featured ) {
    // Post has a featured image; do something with it
} else if ( $first_img ) {
    // Post has attached image; do something with the first one
} else if ( $custom ) {
    // Post has image attached via custom field; do something with it
} else {
    // Otherwise, there's no featured image,
    // no attached images, and no image 
    // defined in post custom meta. Do something.
}
?>
```

You just need to fit in your markup accordingly.

Comment: This is brilliant thank you.

How about if its just text, no featured image, no image attached or video meta data, is that possible?

Comment: Of course! You just need one more `else`. See updated answer.

Comment: I'll give that a go, thank you very much indeed :) (i'll probably break it)